# ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK and restart_syscall confusion

Tags: linux-kernel, signals

It would appear from the source of `nanosleep()` in `kernel/time/hrtimer.c` and the manpage of `restart_syscall()` that to enable `nanosleep()` to be restarted with the correct timeout after a signal, it saves some state into `current_thread_info()->restart_block`, returns `ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK` and that the signal delivery code would arrange for `restart_syscall()` to be called after the signal handler returns to do this. However:

- There is only space in `current_thread_info()->restart_block` for one syscall, so what happens in case of recursive signals?
- The ARM and x86 signal delivery code resets `current_thread_info()->restart_block` before a signal handler is called.
- The ARM signal delivery code does not arrange for `restart_syscall()` to be called, instead it sets the return code to `-EINTR`.

Where is my mistake in the purpose or functioning of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked out that this it to allow a debugger attached using ptrace examine signals and alter the state of the process, and such syscalls return EINTR when interuppted by a signal handler.